# Winform group box is eating my button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a WinForms group box that needs to be sized programmatically.

Everything else is working well but I am having trouble with the below line of code because as the form is re-sized larger the group box grows over the buttons that are underneath.

I am looking for a way in code so that the group box grows with the form, but no so large that it grows over the button underneath it.

```
Const VerticalBuffer As Integer = 10
GroupBox1.Height = ((Me.Height - (3 * VerticalBuffer + 420)) * 0.33)
```

Comment: Switch to WPF and you won't have to deal with nonsense like that...

Comment: love to, though my employer will have to OK a re-write of a company's main application which is 100,000 lines of code.  Will be a hard sell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Anchoring help ? Try setting anchor on the buttons to bottom-right, when form resizes it will follow beneath; but for GroupBox anchor should work too, I think if you set the anchors on group box and resize it, the form should grow.

Comment: I tried; the button is already anchored to the bottom, right and the group box (also anchored bottom right still grows right over it.

Comment: Hmmm anchored GroupBox growing should grow the form I guess :/

Comment: @Anthony Don't resize the groupbox.  Anchor to the top, right and bottom.  It sounds like you are trying to do both: resize and anchor.